# How do I add a column to identify sequences of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, date

I have many rows of appointment member IDs and appointment dates.  I am trying to find a way of roughly identifying sequences of appointments.  For example, below I have user "A" with five appointments on record.  These appear to be two sequences of appointments, one in February, another in May.

`| user |    date    | 
 |  A   |  02-01-2014|
 |  A   |  02-09-2014|
 |  A   |  02-20-2014|
 |  A   |  05-10-2014|
 |  A   |  05-15-2014|
 |  B   |  01-05-2015|
 |  B   |  01-20-2015|`

The output I am trying to come up with is below. I want to be able to pick some threshold, say 45 days, at which point a new sequence will begin.  For example, user "A" had an appointment on 05-10-2014, the first appointment for that user in months.  Therefore, that appointment begins a new sequence in the additional column. The end result is that each user has a set of appointments with an additional column to identify which sequence each row belongs to.

`| user |    date    | Sequence | 
 |  A   |  02-01-2014|    1     |
 |  A   |  02-09-2014|    1     |
 |  A   |  02-20-2014|    1     |
 |  A   |  05-10-2014|    2     |
 |  A   |  05-15-2014|    2     |
 |  B   |  01-05-2015|    1     |
 |  B   |  01-20-2015|    1     |`

I can't seem to find a way to fit this logic into a CASE statement. I would guess the missing piece is being able to reference the previous appointment if it exists. Any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are defining a sequence as beginning with a gap of at least 45 days, then you can do this with window functions:

```
select a.*, sum(SequenceStart) over (partition by user order by date) as seq
from (select a.*,
             (case when date > dateadd(day, 45, lag(date) over (partition by user order by date)) 
                   then 1 else 0 end
              end) as SequenceStart
      from appointment a
     ) a;
```

This uses functionality from SQL Server 2012+.  It is possible in earlier versions as well.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, I failed to mention I am using SQL Server 2008 so it does not like lag().  But I think there may be other ways to reference the previous row so it still helped.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL 2005+, You can use [DENSE_RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx), like this:

```
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [user] ORDER BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, [date]), 0)) AS [Sequence]
FROM Your_Table
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does that handle a specified threshold, e.g. 45 days, before a gap starts a new sequence?

Comment: Have you sample data and sample result?

Comment: I haven't any sample data and results other than that included in the posted question. Is that insufficient?